# java ArrayList remove object while iterating

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I'm running an iterator over an arraylist and am trying to remove an item when a condition is true.

I have the following code:

```
String item = (String) model.getElementAt(selectedIndices[i]);
Iterator it = p.eggMoves.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    String text = (String) it.next();
    if ( text.equals(item) )
    {
        it.remove();
        p.eggMoves.remove(selectedIndices[i]);
        model.removeElementAt(selectedIndices[i]);
    }
}
```

Now this code works fine, the item is removed from both the p object and the jlist, but it throws an "ConcurrentModificationException" exception at the it.next() line.

How do I solve this?

Comment: `The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.`  quotes from JavaDoc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just remove the item by using `it.remove()` while iterating.

Below line is causing the issue

```
p.eggMoves.remove(selectedIndices[i]);
```

---

What you want to do by removing same item (that is at index i) again and again?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to call both `it.remove();` and `p.eggMoves.remove(selectedIndices[i]);`.  The call to `it.remove();` will remove the current item from `p.eggMoves`.

Remove the call to `p.eggMoves.remove(selectedIndices[i]);` and it should work fine.